# Poisson distribution with big numbers

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I failed this question at an exam and would like help in explaining how to solve it: Historical data show that approximately 70 000 vehicles cross Älvsborgsbron every day. What is the probability that more than 7 500 000 vehicles cross Älvsborgsbron in 100 days? For full points you must motivate and explain all assumptions and approximations.

Thanks for the help

Edit: I have tried to use the poisson formula and end up with values that my calculator says doesnt work. I¨ve also tried this \frac{\left(7500000-7000000\right)}{2645.75} but gives my a result of 188,98. So doesnt make sense as I should get a percentage answer. My only though about that number is that it is so high that its basically zero percent chance of happening.

Comment: Hi, welcome ! Please know that on this forum you are expected to first show whatever efforts you have made, and where you are stuck to get necessary help, so do edit it in.

Comment: Hi, okay I understand. My problem is I havent been provided with an correct answer so I have no clue if I´m on the right track

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

1. Assume a normal distribution (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158355/how-large-does-a-poisson-distributions-mean-need-to-be-to-use-normal-distributi) why)
2. Assume a daily standard deviation - let's say $\sigma$ daily is 10,000.
3. Calculate the Z-score for 7,500,000 crossings $$ Z = (7,500,000 - 7,000,000)/100,000 $$

I think your assumption in step 2, where you've assumed a variance of 7,000,000 is wrong and this has led to a very high Z-score.
Your conclusion seems right - there's an extremely low chance of this occurring.

Comment: Okay good to hear. What would be the correct assumption of the variance? I was checking the formulas and in a poisson distribution it said that the population std was the square root of the population mean. But maybe I should divide it by the variance instead?

Comment: This is correct for a Poisson distribution but we're assuming a normal distribution here. I've assumed a standard deviation that is greater than 2645.75 because this seems reasonable from real world data, considering normal variation in traffic. For example, if you look at variability in traffic on the George Washington Bridge for 2023, you see a coefficient of variation (CoV) of 5%. If you use a sd of 2645.75 for Älvsborgsbron, you end up with a CoV of 0.03%, which seems too low.